# connecting android client to rails server

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails

I am a rails beginner and just generated scaffolded models. I am trying to connect this rails server to an android client that my co-founder made.

How can I do this? I was wondering if someone can please simplify the process to a beginner so that I can take the necessary steps to getting this done.

Thank you to anyone that helps!

Comment: why not ask your co-founder? he should know.
I believe you have to run `rails s` inside the project then connect to the ip where you have the client on port 3000.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the Android app's code will include calls to the server's API (via calls to URLs like http://myapp.com/users which are generated by Rails' routes), which will return a response from the database in the Rails app with the data the client will show/evaluate.

You need to work with your cofounder to figure out what type of data is needed on the client, identify those RESTful endpoints and create other methods and routes in rails for those endpoints that are not yet available.

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ios-photo-sharing-geo-location-service
- https://github.com/CabForward/iOS-on-Rails
- http://pnhoang.tumblr.com/post/24160454924/build-a-rails-backend-api-for-an-iphone-client

There are a ton of "Create a Rails API" articles out there, so dig around. If you have more specific questions, let me know and we can add the detail here.